# ios webview css and hyperlinks not working in local html files in container

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, webview

I have a folder structure in the container for my ios app as shown below (inside the Documents folder):

```
/myfolder  
    /images/background.png
    /meta/style.css
    index.html
    lifestyle.html
    news.html
    weather.html
```

I have added a WKWebview to my app by dragging and dropping in the GUI in Main.storyboard, and I load index.html in the webview as follows:

```
NSArray *documentPaths;  
NSString *documentsDir;  
.  
.  
.  
documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];  
documentsDir = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [documentsDir stringByAppendingString:@"/myfolder/index.html"]];  
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDir];  
[self.webMyWebView loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:url ];
```

The webview loads index.html, but only the html parts. It does not load the css file (which should display the image in `/images/background.png`, hence there is no image either). The hyperlinks are there (blue and underlined) and the links are clickable (hyperlinks get a blue background colour when pressed), but the webview does not change to the hyperlinked page (index.html links to lifestyle.html, news.html and weather.html, 3 links on the index page)

style.css loads the image as

```
background: url(../images/background.png)
```

An example link on the index page is

```
<a href="news.html">News</a>
```

How do I get the webview to properly load my local html file? I was able to load google.com in another test program I was making, and the links in it worked just fine, so it seems to be an issue with the local file. Most the questions I have seen here seem to deal with the html files being added into the xcode workspace as part of the project (that is, visible in the project navigator panel on the left). I would like to point out that all my files are in the container, and any additional files that might be added in the future should also stay in the container. All the html files are automatically created as a part of a different decoding process so I don't have the option of changing the contents of the html files.

What needs to be done to load the css and make the links on the webview clickable? I need to do this in objective C.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but I can't guarantee that it will work for you too. But I think **you can try it.**

This is my [project directory structure](http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/large/006tNc79ly1g4fsueddulj30ey0rwmyv.jpg)

```
└─┬WKWebLoadLocalJS
  |
  └─┬WKWebLoadLocalJS
    |
    ├─┬framework7-master
    | |
    | └─┬kitchen-sink
    |   |
    |   └─┬core
    |     |
    |     └──index.html
    |
    ├──AppDelegate.h 
    |    
    ├──AppDelegate.m
    |
    ├──ViewController
    | 
    |
    └ …
```

```
- (void)loadLocalJS {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    //Folder path in the project
    NSString *directoryPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"framework7-master" ofType:@""];
    //Tmp cache folder path
    NSString *tmpPath = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    //Create a newDir (any name) folder under the tmp folder
    NSString *newDir =@"newDir";
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[tmpPath stringByAppendingString:newDir] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    //The path to the newDir folder in tmp
    NSString *tmp_newDir_path = [tmpPath stringByAppendingString:newDir];
    //Copy folder to the tmp/newDir path
    NSError*error;
    NSString*txtPath =[tmp_newDir_path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"framework7-master"];
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:txtPath]){
        NSLog(@"***** Copy folder to the tmp/newDir path：%d*****",[fileManager copyItemAtPath:directoryPath toPath:txtPath error:&error]);
    }
    //Tmp/newDir/FeedbackH5/pages/feedback.html full path
    NSString *tmp_newDir_Feedback = [tmp_newDir_path stringByAppendingString:@"/framework7-master/kitchen-sink/core/index.html"];
    //Convert path to URL
    NSURL *feedbackURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tmp_newDir_Feedback];
    //WKWebView
    [self.web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:feedbackURL]];
}
```

If you don't understand, you can see this [example](https://github.com/sshallow/WKWebLoadLocalJS.git).

I hope it can help you.

Comment: my html file is in the container